# Use date in column as column header in query result

Tags: mysql, sql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=362207c6cc04749aade4a74f543c7ac7)**

```
CREATE TABLE operations (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    time_stamp DATE,
    product VARCHAR(255),
    quantity INT
);

INSERT INTO operations
(time_stamp, product, quantity
)
VALUES 
("2020-01-01", "Product_A", "600"),
("2020-01-01", "Product_B", "400"),
("2020-01-01", "Product_C", "700"),
("2020-03-15", "Product_A", "300"),
("2020-03-15", "Product_B", "500"),
("2020-03-15", "Product_C", "900"),
("2020-03-15", "Product_D", "150");
```

**Expected Result:**

```
Product           2020-01-01       2020-03-15  
Product_A             600              300
Product_B             400              500
Product_C             700              900
Product_D               0              150
```

---

In the above result I want to dispaly the `quantity` per `time_stamp` in two different columns. 
For this I use the below query:

```
SELECT
product,
SUM(CASE WHEN time_stamp = '2020-01-01' THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS time_stamp_01,
SUM(CASE WHEN time_stamp = '2020-03-15' THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS time_stamp_02
FROM operations 
GROUP BY 1;
```

As you can see in the query the columns are named `time_stamp_01` and `time_stamp_02`. 
However, I want that the date is used `2020-01-01` and `2020-03-15`. 
What do I need to change in the query to achieve this?

---

**NOTE:** There will be always **only two** `time_stamps` in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have *fixed* dates, you can use them as column names, but they need to be escaped:

```
SELECT product,
       SUM(CASE WHEN time_stamp = '2020-01-01' THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS `2020-01-01`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN time_stamp = '2020-03-15' THEN quantity ELSE 0 END) AS `2020-03-15`
FROM operations 
GROUP BY 1;
```

If you want to pull the values from the table, then you need to use dynamic SQL.